# Async / Await fails in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I am having some issues with Async/Await when trying to process my MSSQL Query.
The query works fine because if i do

```
console.log(sqltest.getNextId("A"))
```

I get the expected result. But i need to wait for the result from first query to pass on to second one so i tried below. Am i missing here something ? I would like to keep it as clean as possible because i might have the need to execute more then 2 in Sequence.

```
async function someMethod() {
var newId = await sqltest.getNextId("A")

var nextId = await sqltest.updateId("A",newId)
console.log(newId + ' - ' + nextId)

}

someMethod()
```

Here is what my getNextId looks like

```
const getNextId = (counter_id) =>

    {const params = [{ name: "p_counter_id", type: sql.VarChar(10), value: counter_id }]
    sqlUtil
    .storedProcedure(params, "sp_counter_sel")
    .then(result => 
        {
        var newCounter = sequence
            (
            result.recordset[0].next_id,
            result.recordset[0].counter_length,
            result.recordset[0].counter_fill
            )

            console.log(newCounter)
            return newCounter
        }
        )
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error: ' + err.message)
            })

}
```

ok to eliminate all confusion here is my .storedProcedure code

```
let storedProcedure = async (params, storedProcedureName) => {
const pool = await getOrCreatePool()
let request = await pool.request()
params.forEach((parameter) => {
    parameterDirection = parameter.isOutput ? 'output' : 'input';
    request = request[parameterDirection](parameter.name, parameter.type, parameter.value)
})
try {
    return await request.execute(storedProcedureName)
    sql.on('error', err => {
    })

}  catch(err) {
    let message = {
        message: {
                msg: err.message,
                number: err.number
            },

    }
    throw message;
}
}
```

Comment: If logging `sqltest.getNextId("A")` shows you the expected result (rather than a `Promise`) then I don't think it's an `aync` method at all. What error messages are you getting? What is being logged to the console?

Comment: What exactly does `sqltest.getNextId("A")` return?  Does it return a value?  A promise?  Is it asynchronous?  Is there API documentation for `getNextId()` or if it's your function, can you show us the code for that?

Comment: Same questions for `updateId()`.  Can we see code or doc?  await does something useful when you are awaiting a promise.  It doesn't do anything useful in pretty much any other circumstance.

Comment: You still haven't shown the error messages you're getting, or what is happening instead of what you expect. What is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: There is no underhanded error it just returns undefined - undefined for the console.log

Comment: i mean... you never returned anything... of course it's returning undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is no underhanded error it just returns undefined - undefined for the console.log

This comment is actually is the important bit!

`getNextId` does not actually return anything, not the value you are looking for, and not a promise that you can `await`. The reason you are seeing output is that `getNextId` runs a `console.log` in the `then` callback.

But `console.log(sqltest.getNextId("A"))` is probably spitting out an `undefined`

Since `sqlUtil.storedProcedure` seems to return a promise (you can tell because you call `then()` on it, you should be able to convert this to an async function, and `await` on that.

```
const getNextId = async (counter_id) => {
    const params = [{
        name: "p_counter_id",
        type: sql.VarChar(10),
        value: counter_id
    }]

    const result = await sqlUtil.storedProcedure(params, "sp_counter_sel")

    var newCounter = sequence(
        result.recordset[0].next_id,
        result.recordset[0].counter_length,
        result.recordset[0].counter_fill
    )

    return newCounter
}

console.log(await getNextId("A")); // Should be what you expect.
```

This function now has a return value. Because it is now `async` and has a `return` statement that is not nested inside another function. It now returns a `Promise` that resolves to `newCounter`, and can be called with `await`.

Comment: Yes turning my function into a async function made it work just fine